# _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "frame" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, mysql, database, tkinter

Im trying to enter to the menu window but whenever I do so I get the cant invoke frame command. I am not sure if there is an error regarding with my .mainloop() function

Here is my login code

```
class Login:
    global user
    global pwd
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Scheduling Management System")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

    self.txt_user = StringVar()
    self.txt_pass = StringVar()
    self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
    bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    framelogin = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
    framelogin.place(x=450, y=100, height=500, width=700)

    registerbutton = Button(framelogin, text="Sign Up", command=self.register, bg="white", fg="orange",
                            font=("trebuchet ms", 12)).place(x=510, y=305)

    loginbutton = Button(framelogin, text="Login", command=self.login, fg="white", bg="orange",
                         font=("sans serif ms", 20)).place(x=90, y=350, width="100", height="40")

def login(self):
    global con
    user = self.txt_user.get().strip()
    pwd = self.txt_pass.get().strip()
    if user == "" or pwd == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")
    else:
        try :
            con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="employee")
            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select 1 from employeelist where username=%s and password=%s", (user,pwd))
            if cur.rowcount == 1:
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Login Successful", parent=self.root)
                self.menu()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong Username or Password. Please try again!")
        except Exception as ex:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
        finally:
            con.close()



def register(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    register.RegisterForm()

def menu(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    menu.MenuForm()

def LoginForm():
    win = Tk()
    obj = Login(win)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is my menu code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image
import login

class Menu:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Main Menu")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root, image=self.bg).place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        framemenu = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        framemenu.place(x=450, y=100, height=500, width=700)
        welcometitle = Label(framemenu, text="Welcome " + login.Login.user, font=("Arial", 30, "bold"), fg="orange", bg="white").place(x=470,
                                                                                                                                       y=120)
def MenuForm():
    win = Tk()
    obj = Menu(win)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Menu(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I cant seem to identify the issue as Im trying to redirect the users once it has login to the menu page

Comment: Since there are issues in your `menu.py`, for example `Tk` is not defined,  so when running `self.menu()` inside `login()` triggers the exception handler to show the error using `messagebox.showerror()`.  However at that time, the root window has already been destroyed, so the mentioned exception is raised.

Comment: @acw1668 How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Fix `menu.py` so that it can be executed without error.

Comment: @acw1668 i thought i have already defined `Tk()` as `win`

Comment: You did not import tkinter in `menu.py`.

Comment: @acw1668 I did, sorry I didn't include in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228185/discussion-between-jagdeesh-sandhu-and-acw1668).